# Volume of a rectangular solid

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume, rectangles

**Compare :**

Quantity A :  The volume of a rectangular solid with sides of x, 2y and 3z
Quantity B :  The volume of a rectangular solid with sides of 3x, y and z

**Options:**

A) Quantity A > Quantity B

B) Quantity A < Quantity B

C) Quantity A = Quantity B

D) Cannot be determined

---

My solution:

Volume =  l * b * h

Quantity A :  6xyz

Quantity B :  3xyz

Now even if all x,y,z are 1, A > B

If x,y,z are fractions, still A > B

Hence,   Option A) Quantity A > Quantity B

---

Is this solution correct ? Can l, b or h be taken as 0 for volume to be 0?

Comment: The separation into those cases it is not necessary. However, one important part of the argument, worth making explicit, is to use that $x,y,z>0$, which allows you to pass from $6>3$ to $6x>3x$ to $6xy>3xy$ and finally $6xyz>3xyz$.

Comment: Means when volume, area or  length is used in a question, they have to have value.  Thanks, that clears the doubt.

Comment: x,y and z should be >0...  otherwise you don't get a rectangular solid...

Answer (score 0):

As Hellen states in their answer, breaking up your solution into cases is not necessary. In fact, $6xyz > 3xyz$ is true for any $x,y,z >0$.

To further justify this answer, think about it this way: $2 > 1 \Rightarrow 2x>x$ if $x>0$. So for your case, $6>3 \Rightarrow 6xyz > 3xyz$, as long as $xyz >0$, which it is.

One final way to think about it is to take the difference between $6xyz$ and $3xyz$.

$$6xyz-3xyz = 3xyz, \text{which is always positive. }$$